# Android Studio: Auto Refresh view when editing the xml for a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, ide

I'd like to work with they `layout.xml` code open on one monitor where I am editing the code, and the layout preview running on my other monitor. I can get this setup working, but what I really want is for the layout to refresh automatically everytime the code is changed, or at least every time the code is saved. Currently, I have to click the preview, at which point it updates.

Answer (score 0):

Jimu Mirror

see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbI61uj8_LE)

Actually I have not used this. But it might be the one you are looking for.

ps - It seems that it is not free :(

also you could report from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html) to android studio